# How this code to find difference betwen two array of objects works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecma

I've tested this code from an answer from SO, it basically returns only the items that exists in array 1 that not exists in array 2. But i can't figure out how this works, can someone explain me?

```
const arrayOne = [ 
  { value: "4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display: "Jamsheer" },
  { value: "644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display: "Muhammed" },
  { value: "b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display: "Ravi" },
  { value: "e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display: "Ajmal" },
  { value: "a63a6f77-c637-454e-abf2-dfb9b543af6c", display: "Ryan" },
];

const arrayTwo = [
  { value: "4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display: "Jamsheer"},
  { value: "644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display: "Muhammed"},
  { value: "b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display: "Ravi"},
  { value: "e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display: "Ajmal"},
];

const results = arrayOne.filter(({ value: id1 }) => !arrayTwo.some(({ value: id2 }) => id2 === id1));

console.log(results);
```

I think `{ value: id1 }` is destructuring assignment, but it seems to swap the key and value??? And what relation with  `id2 === id1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `{ value: id1 }` Assign a property to a variable with another name.

For example:

```js
({ a:id, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 });
console.log(id); // 10
console.log(a); // "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"
```

2. After assigning the `value` to `id1` & `id2`, now we can check the `id1` in `arrayOne` and `id2` in `arrayTwo`

```js
const arrayOne = [ 
  { value: "4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display: "Jamsheer" },
  { value: "644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display: "Muhammed" },
  { value: "b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display: "Ravi" },
  { value: "e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display: "Ajmal" },
  { value: "a63a6f77-c637-454e-abf2-dfb9b543af6c", display: "Ryan" },
];

const arrayTwo = [
  { value: "4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display: "Jamsheer"},
  { value: "644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display: "Muhammed"},
  { value: "b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display: "Ravi"},
  { value: "e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display: "Ajmal"},
];

const results = arrayOne.filter(
                        ({ value : id1  }) => !arrayTwo.some(
                                            ({ value: id2 }) => id2 === id1)
                );
console.log(results);
```

**The same solution**

```
const results = arrayOne.filter(
                        item1 => !arrayTwo.some( item2 => item1.value === item2.value)
                );
console.log(results);
```

```js
const arrayOne = [ 
  { value: "4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display: "Jamsheer" },
  { value: "644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display: "Muhammed" },
  { value: "b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display: "Ravi" },
  { value: "e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display: "Ajmal" },
  { value: "a63a6f77-c637-454e-abf2-dfb9b543af6c", display: "Ryan" },
];

const arrayTwo = [
  { value: "4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display: "Jamsheer"},
  { value: "644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display: "Muhammed"},
  { value: "b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display: "Ravi"},
  { value: "e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display: "Ajmal"},
];

// The same solution
const results = arrayOne.filter(
                        item1 => !arrayTwo.some( item2 => item1.value === item2.value)
                );
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best way to understand it is to do a refactoring using some old school vanilla JS:

```js
const results = arrayOne.filter(objectOne => {
  return !arrayTwo.some(objectTwo => {
    return objectOne.value === objectTwo.value;
  })
});
```

Here I didn't use object destructuring nor omitted `return` keyword, it made things a bit more clear.